# Eclipse PDE Plugin Export

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a plugin for eclipse via PDE. I can try the plugin by running the project as 'eclipse application', no problem so far. However, I want to export the project and I get this error:

> C:\Users\ErayT\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:88: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:103: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:26: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\Documents\Courses\Senior_Project\workspace\AssignmentGrader\AssignmentGrader_Plugin\build.xml:282: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\Documents\Courses\Senior_Project\workspace\AssignmentGrader\AssignmentGrader_Plugin\build.xml:362: Problem: failed to create task or type apitooling.apigeneration
>   Cause: The name is undefined.
>   Action: Check the spelling.
>   Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>   Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
>
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:103: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.win32.win32.x86_64.xml:26: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\Documents\Courses\Senior_Project\workspace\AssignmentGrader\AssignmentGrader_Plugin\build.xml:282: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\ErayT\Documents\Courses\Senior_Project\workspace\AssignmentGrader\AssignmentGrader_Plugin\build.xml:362: Problem: failed to create task or type apitooling.apigeneration
>   Cause: The name is undefined.
>   Action: Check the spelling.
>   Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
>   Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

It says there is an error in the file build.xml. Actually there is no file named like this. That is the other strange feedback message I get.

I do not know where to start to solve the problem unfortunately. Those errors do not make sense for me and no idea what really is going on.

Comment: Looks similar to this: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/199754/

Answer (score 1):

I have updated my eclipse with the PDE API tools.

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what was missing for me!